# Is there a way to display list objects one record at a time

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic4

```html
<ion-list>
  <div>
    <ion-list>
      <div *ngFor="let itinerary of filteredItineraries">
        <ion-card class="itinerary-module">
          <ion-card-content *ngIf="itinerary.id !== selection.id">
            <div>
              <h2>{{itinerary.startDate | date: "MM/dd/yyyy"}} - {{itinerary.endDate | date: "MM/dd/yyyy"}}</h2>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h1>{{itinerary.jobDesc}}</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h2>{{itinerary.jobCode}}</h2>
            </div>
            <ion-item lines="none">
                <ion-icon slot="start" name="thumbs-down" (click)="removeItem(itinerary.id)></ion-icon>
                <ion-icon slot="end" name="thumbs-up" (click)="removeItem(itinerary.id)" ></ion-icon>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
      </div>
    </ion-list>
  </div>
</ion-list>
```

Is there a way to only display this list one item at a time...say index 0, then when I click one of the icons to remove the current item in index 0 so that index 1 then moves to 0 and is displayed on the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Do not iterate over the loop and render. Just point the UI to first element `filteredItenaries[0]`
- If you want to show the next item, call a function which has the implementation `filteredIternaries.splice(0,1)`. So, therefore, the first element will be updated in the Array as well as in the UI.

Comment: so instead of <div *ngFor="let itinerary of filteredItineraries"> would I just have ngModel=[filteredItenaries]